# Why doesn't Win32 ReadFile() preserve order of bytes when written to a uint16_t array buffer

Tags: c++, winapi, readfile, cl

I have a binary file, with the following data:

```
00e0 a248 6000 611e 6200 d202 d212 7208
3240 120a 6000 613e 6202 a24a d02e d12e
...
```

When I use `ReadFile()` and set the target buffer to a `uint8_t` array, the written buffer data matches the source file data:

```
uint8_t rom[256];
ReadFile(_, rom, _, NULL, NULL);
// in rom
rom[0x00000000] 0x00
rom[0x00000001] 0xe0
rom[0x00000002] 0xa2
rom[0x00000003] 0x48
rom[0x00000004] 0x60
rom[0x00000005] 0x00
rom[0x00000006] 0x61
...
```

Why is it when I use `ReadFile()` with a `uint16_t` array, each element has the bytes written in backwards?

```
uint16_t rom[256];
ReadFile(_, rom, _, NULL, NULL);
// in rom
rom[0x00000000] 0xe000
rom[0x00000001] 0x48a2
rom[0x00000002] 0x0060
rom[0x00000003] 0x1e61
rom[0x00000004] 0x0062
rom[0x00000005] 0x02d2
rom[0x00000006] 0x12d2
...
```

The same pattern seems to exist with larger types as well:

```
uint32_t rom[256];
ReadFile(_, rom, _, NULL, NULL);
// in rom
rom[0x00000000] 0x48a2e000
rom[0x00000001] 0x1e610060
rom[0x00000002] 0x02d20062
rom[0x00000003] 0x087212d2
rom[0x00000004] 0x0a124032
rom[0x00000005] 0x3e610060
rom[0x00000006] 0x4aa20262
...
```

the documentation for [`ReadFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile#parameters) doesn't seem to mention anything about this behavior

Comment: The real issue here is one of human perception. While it is conventional to write bytes of memory in increasing address order from left to right, it is equally conventional to write digits in a number in increasing significance from right to left. On a little-endian platform this creates the illusion that the byte order were swapped, but really isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ReadFile()` has no concept of the kind of buffer you are reading into. It only reads raw bytes. And it does preserve the order of the bytes.

Multi-byte integers (`uint16_t` is 2 bytes, `uint32_t` is 4 bytes) are subject to [**endian**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) (ie, **byte order**), that is what you are experiencing. The bytes themselves are not being reversed. The *values* of the integers depend on the *order* in which the bytes are *interpreted*.  The same byte sequence can represent different numeric values depending on whether the bytes are interpreted in **little endian** or **big endian** byte order.

For example, the 2-byte sequence `00 e0` represents a `uint16_t` value of `53744` (hex 0xE000) in little endian, and of `224` (hex 0x00E0) in big endian.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that one can convert the in-memory array from big-endian format to native-endian format by running each value in the array through `ntohs()` (for 16-bit values) or `ntohl()` (for 32-bit values).